# Nested Elements within Simple Form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

I am trying to use Simple Form with my Rails 4 app.

I have models called projects.rb and programs.rb. Each of those 2 models has some common components. I handle these with another model called scope.rb. Each of projects and programs has a scope.

Within scopes, I have models called data.rb and materials.rb.

In my projects view, I ask several threshold questions. One of them is do you want data? (the answers true or false) The answer to that question is stored in my scope model. If the answer is true, then I want to ask further questions about the data (the answers are stored in my data model).

So, the relationships are that each of programs & projects has one scope. Each of data and materials belongs to scope.

For the moment, all of those data model questions are set out in my projects view.

The projects view when everything is set out in the projects view is as follows:

This is the scope question to find out whether further detail is required about data or materials:

```
 <div class="col-md-3 col-md-offset-1">
              <%= f.label  'What sort resources are involved in this project?',   :class => 'question-project' %>
            </div>
           <div class="col-md-7">
              <div class="response-project" style="margin-left:5%">
                <%= f.simple_fields_for :scope do |s_all| %>
                 <%= s_all.input :if_datum, :as => :boolean, :label => false, inline_label: 'Data' %>
                 <%= s_all.input :if_material, :as => :boolean, :label => false,  inline_label: 'Equipment or materials' %>
                <% end %>
              </div>
             </div>
           </div>
```

If the answer to data is true, then I ask:

```
  <div class="col-md-3 col-md-offset-1">
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-7">
    <%= f.simple_fields_for :scope do |data_s| %>
        <%= data_s.simple_fields_for :datum do |d| %>
            <%= d.label  'Is this data confidential or commercially sensitive?',   :class => 'response-project' %> <br>
            <%= d.collection_radio_buttons :confidential, [[true, '  Yes       '] ,[false, '     No']], :first, :last, {:item_wrapper_class => 'inline'}, {:class => "radio-inline response-project" } %>
            <%= d.input :prim_sec, label: 'What sort of data do you want?', label_html: {class: 'response-project'}, collection: ["Primary", "Secondary", "Both" ], prompt: "Choose one", item_wrapper_class: 'inline' %>
        <% end %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

This all works fine, except that i want to use the same forms in my programs model. That's why I'm trying to extract them into partial views in my data model so that I can use them in both the projects and programs models.

When I start with the data/_form view, with this extracted:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-3 col-md-offset-1">
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-7">
    <%= f.simple_fields_for :scope do |data_s| %>
        <%= data_s.simple_fields_for :datum do |d| %>
            <%= d.label  'Is this data confidential or commercially sensitive?',   :class => 'response-project' %> <br>
            <%= d.collection_radio_buttons :confidential, [[true, '  Yes       '] ,[false, '     No']], :first, :last, {:item_wrapper_class => 'inline'}, {:class => "radio-inline response-project" } %>
            <%= d.input :prim_sec, label: 'What sort of data do you want?', label_html: {class: 'response-project'}, collection: ["Primary", "Secondary", "Both" ], prompt: "Choose one", item_wrapper_class: 'inline' %>
        <% end %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

And replace that code in my project view to render "data/form".

My problem is that when I move the data code to a data/_form to ask the data specific questions, I get the errors set out below. My view, when I try to do this is:

undefined local variable or method `f' for #<#:0x00000107ff3a90>

This is a reference to the line in the data/_form view that says:

```
    <%= f.simple_fields_for :scope do |data_s| %>
```

Does anyone know what I've done wrong?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you are doing something like this:

```
<%= simple_form_for project do |f| %>
  <%= render 'data/form' %>
<% end %>
```

When rendering a partial, local variables are not passed down. So if you need to access `f` within your `data/_form` partial, you need to provide your partial with a corresponding local variable. Try this:

```
<%= simple_form_for project do |f| %>
  <%= render 'data/form', f: f %>
<% end %>
```

Or, in a more verbose fashion:

```
<%= simple_form_for project do |f| %>
  <%= render partial: 'data/form', locals: {f: f} %>
<% end %>
```

HTH!